# Groovy GString rendering does not call overridden toString() method when parent is Map or Collection

Tags: groovy, gstring

Here is minimal demo case:

```
class T extends HashMap {
  @Override
  String toString() {
    return "foo"
  }
}

def t = new T()
println t.toString()
println "${t}"​
```

The output is

```
foo
[:]
```

So the `@Override toString()` never executed for obtaining value within `GString`. Should I put breakpoint inside it never stopped there. Am I missing something or is it a bug? Other than `HashMap` and `Collection` seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 4):

`GString` does not call `Map.toString()` directly and instead it calls

```
InvokeHelper.write(Writer out, Object object)
```

Put breakpoint [here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/InvokerHelper.java#L517) and see what happens:

I've recorded a short video from debugging session to show you exactly what happens when this object is put inside a GString:

> https://youtu.be/HYHdfmwd-lw

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, this is clear now what happening. Though I am still consider question unanswered because to me it is unclear is it expected behaviour (and if so - why) or is it sounds like a Groovy bug. I am surprised `instanceof Map` give me `true` as for subclassed in Java you always had to use `isAssignableFrom()` for it. I am surprised I am no longer able to threat `Map` as an object in Groovy and customize it's behaviour with inheritance as I need. Anyway is there a workaround available?

Comment: I think I found a workaround by using `println "${(String) t}"​` which will force it to cast to String which will call `toString()` even before `GString` will start rendering.

Comment: You can call `t.toString()` directly without casting. It doesn't change the order of  rendering inside `GString`, it changes types that `GString` is about to render - now it sees `String` instead of a `Map` so it renders it as is.